# C# event with custom arguments

Tags: c#, events

I want to have an event that takes an enum only as the argument. For example

```
public enum MyEvents{
   Event1
}

// how do I declare this to take enum MyEvents as argument
public static event EventHandler EventTriggered;

public static void Trigger(MyEvent event )
{
    if (EventTriggered != null)
    {
        EventTriggered(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You declare a delegate for the parameters:

```
public enum MyEvents { Event1 }

public delegate void MyEventHandler(MyEvents e);

public static event MyEventHandler EventTriggered;
```

Although all events in the framework takes a parameter that is or derives from `EventArgs`, you can use any parameters you like. However, people are likely to expect the pattern used in the framework, which might make your code harder to follow.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I agree with your comments.

Comment: You can shorten that as `public static event Action<MyEvents> EventTriggered;`

Answer (score 76):

`EventHandler` receives `EventArgs` as a parameter. To resolve your problem, you can build your own `MyEventArgs`.

```
 public enum MyEvents
 { 
    Event1 
 }

 public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
 {
    public MyEvents MyEvent { get; set; }
 }

 public static event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> EventTriggered; 

 public static void Trigger(MyEvents ev) 
 { 
     if (EventTriggered != null) 
     {
         EventTriggered(null, new MyEventArgs { MyEvent = ev });
     } 
 }
```

Comment: What's the difference between event EventHandler<T> EventName (Your proposal) and public delegate void NewEventHandler(object sender, T e); public event NewEventHandler EventInstanceName; Which of them is "better" and why?

Comment: @Prokurors the former is "better" because it saves you from declaring a delegate which is actually a duplicate of `EventHandler<T>`.

Comment: I didn't know there was an `EventHandler<T>`! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I might be late in the game, but how about:

```
public event Action<MyEvent> EventTriggered = delegate { }; 

private void Trigger(MyEvent e) 
{ 
     EventTriggered(e);
}
```

Setting the event to an anonymous delegate avoids for me to check to see if the event isn't null.

I find this comes in handy when using MVVM, like when using ICommand.CanExecute Method.

Comment: fantastic example using existing classes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare a custom eventhandler.

```
public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs
{
  ...
}

public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

public class MyControl: UserControl
{
  public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a reworking of your sample to get you started.

- your sample has a static event - it's more usual for an event to come from a class instance, but I've left it static below.
- the sample below also uses the more standard naming OnXxx for the method that raises the event.
- the sample below does not consider thread-safety, which may well be more of an issue if you insist on your event being static.

.

```
public enum MyEvents{ 
     Event1 
} 

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(MyEvents myEvents)
    {
        MyEvents = myEvents;
    }

    public MyEvents MyEvents { get; private set; }
}

public static class MyClass
{
     public static event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> EventTriggered; 

     public static void Trigger(MyEvents myEvents) 
     {
         OnMyEvent(new MyEventArgs(myEvents));
     }

     protected static void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e)
     {
         if (EventTriggered != null)
         {
             // Normally the first argument (sender) is "this" - but your example
             // uses a static event, so I'm passing null instead.
             // EventTriggered(this, e);
             EventTriggered(null, e);
         } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum MyEvents
{
    Event1
}

public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEvents MyEvents { get; set; }
}


private EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> onTrigger;

public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> Trigger
{
    add
    {
        onTrigger += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        onTrigger -= value;
    }
}

protected void OnTrigger(CustomEventArgs e)
{
    if (onTrigger != null)
    {
        onTrigger(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with no parameters:

```
delegate void NewEventHandler();
public event NewEventHandler OnEventHappens;
```

And from another class, you can subscribe to

```
otherClass.OnEventHappens += ExecuteThisFunctionWhenEventHappens;
```

And declare that function with no parameters.