# c# creating events without delegates like VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My Code in VB.net

```vb
Public Class Form1
    'step 1. declare the event
    Private Event TestEvent(ByVal msg As String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'step 2. raise the event
        RaiseEvent TestEvent("Hello World")
    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_load()
    'step 3. add the event handler
    AddHandler Me.TestEvent, AddressOf test_handler
Sub

Private Sub test_handler(ByVal message As String)
    MsgBox(message)
End Sub
End Class
```

My Code in C#

```
namespace CSharp_Event_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //step 1. declare delegate of event
        private delegate void TestEventHandler(string msg);
        //step 2. declare the event
        private event TestEventHandler ActualTestEvent;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //step 3. raise the event
            ActualTestEvent("Hello World");
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //step 4. Specify the event handler
            this.ActualTestEvent += new TestEventHandler(test_event);
        }

        private  void test_event(string M) {
            MessageBox.Show(text: M, caption: "Event Raised");
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them work actually. Im just curious why I was able to declare an event in VB even without a delegate but in C# making events without delegate gives me an error.

Comment: Where is the code that gives you an error? And, what is the error? `this.ActualTestEvent += test_event;`  should work.

Comment: yeah its working because i already declared a delegate for the event. Is there any way to declare events in c# in the same manner as vb.net?

Comment: VB is using the implicit delegate implied by the event declaration.  There is no such feature in C#.  VB has 2 ways of declaring an event - one with an implied delegate (VB weirdness), and one which uses an explicit delegate.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - I'd post that as an answer, if I were you. It's spot on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Q:** I'm just curious why I was able to declare an event in VB even without a delegate but in C# making events without delegate gives me an error.

As explained in [this article on delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx), it's because VB.NET is capable of implicitly declaring a delegate type for you when declaring an event:

> Although you can create your own delegates, in most cases Visual Basic creates the delegate and takes care of the details for you. For example, an `Event` statement ***implicitly defines a delegate class*** named `<EventName>EventHandler` as a nested class of the class containing the `Event` statement, and with the same signature as the event.

Unfortunately, C# doesn't provide this convenient syntactic sugar, so you have to *explicitly* declare the delegate type before declaring the event. (Or, as observed in Adam's answer, you can reuse existing delegate types)

Answer (score 3):

See also [C# event with custom arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742022/c-sharp-event-with-custom-arguments)

```
class Program
{
    public static event Action<string> myEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myEvent += Program_myEvent1;
        myEvent("Cheese");
    }

    private static void Program_myEvent1(string val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The trick is to use `Action<T>` instead of EventHandler

Comment: How does this answer the question? Both `Action<T>` and `EventHandler` are simply built-in delegates. This is nothing different from the OP's code.

Comment: My understanding is that OP doesn't want to eliminate the delegate, the goal is to eliminate writing the delegate explicitly.

Comment: Can you tell me where in the question he asks that?

Comment: This statement "Im just curious why I was able to declare an event in VB even without a delegate but in C# making events without delegate gives me an error." indicates that OP believes VB doesn't use a delegate, so he would not be able to ask the question explicitly. But people asking this question are probably looking for a solution that is similar to VB.