# WPF passing text from one window to another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main window and it has a button. When I press the main window button, it will open sub-window. In sub window, I have a text box and when I enter the text and click the add button in sub-window, the text should display on the main window. How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is why do you need this? Is it small aplication with just one call like this? Or will you need tens of these? Will you have just two window?

Comment: Its a application where in i have many sub windows but i'm stuck with this problem rest all windows are working fine.its only with this window i'm not getting the text from sub window to main window.

Comment: The dirty ways: Static property, passing the reference to mainWindow by constructor or any other method, getting MainWindow by Application.Current.(...). Not so bad: IoC, and getting window from container. Good: EventAggregator/listener/observer/mediator/messenger oop

Comment: Or create event in subWindow, subscribe to it from window, and fire it with buton

Comment: I have created a event in sub window but but not able to bring it to main window with that button

Comment: when enter the text in sub window it is getting displayed in the sub window itself i want that text to be displayed in main window

Comment: Did you subscribed to it by += in your mainWindow when creating new instance of sub window? You can pass text as eventArgs

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742047  Following this sample, you can use String as param in MyArgs, and in button just call trigger with this param

Answer (score 3):

You can create parameterized constructor of MainWindow class and pass value of Textbox from subwindow to main window and in MainWindow you can set content to that label.
Here is the implementation
**MainWindow.xmal.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow ()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
    public MainWindow (string text) : this()
    {
        label.Content = text;

    }
    private void button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        win1.Show();
        this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for **subWindow i.e. Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
    private string text;
    public Window1 ()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        text = textBox.Text;
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(text);
        mainWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This violates seperation principles

Comment: here is sample code which i'm trying in my application

Comment: main window XAML file

Comment: You can try with this as well in button_Click event of Window1 class
    mainWindow.label.Content = textBox.Text;

Comment: I tried your method but still not able to get the text in main window.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify the constructor of the second window :

```
   public partial class Window1 : Window
   {
     string text;
     public Window1 (string _text)
     {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.text = _text;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add an event to your 'dialog' subwindow which the MainWindow can subscribe to as it instantiates it.

**DialogWindow:** (subwindow):

```
public class DialogInputEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
}

public partial class DialogWindow : Window
{
    public event EventHandler<DialogInputEventArgs> InputChanged = delegate { };

    private void SubmitInputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputChanged(this, new DialogInputEventArgs() { Input = this._inputTextBox.Text });
    }
}
```

**MainWindow:**

```
private void ShowDialogButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogWindow dw = new DialogWindow();
    dw.InputChanged += OnDialogInputChanged;
    dw.Show();
}

private void OnDialogInputChanged(object sender, DialogInputEventArgs e)
{
    // update the MainWindow somehow using e.Input (the text submitted in dialog)
}
```

If you need this mechanism for multiple windows I would go with something more generic, like a messagebus or observerpattern thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use CaliburnMicro framwework to achieve easier and better communication between your controls (assuming you are using MVVM pattern). You don't have to implement all features of CaliburnMicro, just EventAggregator to manage sending and handling messages between your controls.