# how to create custom event for my property

Tags: c#, wpf, events, dependency-properties

I have a property for my custom control.

Now I want to create a `ValueChanged` event for my property. (I don't need callback for my property as I want user can use this event)

```
 public double Value
 {
    get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", 
        typeof(double), typeof(SpeedoMeter), 
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, null, OnCoerceValueChanged));
```

Comment: Register a dependency property callback and raise a public event in it?

Comment: Consider deriving your control from [RangeBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase?view=netframework-4.8). It alread has a Value property with a ValueChanged event.

Comment: @Clemens i do it but when value changed nothing happened

Comment: And you do not declare the Value property again?

Comment: @Clemens i write code like this  protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
        {
            base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
         
        }

Comment: You don't need to overwite *anything* when you derive from RangeBase. Just apply a ControlTemplate via a default Style in `Themes\Generic.xaml`. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an event as usual (it may be defined as [routed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event) if it makes sense) and then register a dependency property callback where you raise this event. Something like this:

```
public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

public double Value
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(SpeedoMeter), new PropertyMetadata(0.0,
        OnChanged,
        OnCoerceValueChanged));

private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SpeedoMeter speedoMeter = (SpeedoMeter)d;
    EventHandler handler = speedoMeter.ValueChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(speedoMeter, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Obviously you may name your event and property whatever you want. If you have a `Value` property and want a `ValueChanged` event, you may for example derive from something like `RangeBase` or similar. This is just an example of how you would raise a custom event when a dependency property changes.

Comment: It should be a RoutedEvent in a WPF control. Don't do this at all. Derive from RangeBase.

Comment: Whether the event should be routed depends. It's perfectly fine for a WPF control to raise an event that is not routed.

Comment: That's too cheap, especially when there already is a control where you can steal all this.

Comment: @Clemens: As I mention in the answer, there is no need to reinvent the wheel if you don't have to for some reason. But the question was how to raise an event in reponse to a dependency property being changed.

Comment: @mm8 your code work but cant get value from eventarg

Comment: Where we "experts" should recommend not to implement it at all.

Comment: You can get it directly from the `Value` property. The other option would be to define a custom `EventArgs`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742022/c-sharp-event-with-custom-arguments